# Using functions in Java Programming

Tags: java, function

I have doubt in using functions in java. I have wrote code for sum of natural numbers using a recursive function but I don't understand the error I am getting. I know it's a silly question though I'm a beginner and I need a brief explanation.

Here is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class natural {

public static int main(String args[]){ 


        int a, s = 0,y; 
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number:");
        int x = in.nextInt();
        public static int SN(y)
        {
            if(x==1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else{
                int N = SN(x-1) + x;
                return N;
                System.out.println("THE SUM IS :"+x);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please complete your code.

Comment: statements after a return statement never get executed. Your IDE will warn you about this. We are not here to debug your code.

Comment: Also it would be helpful to post the errors you are getting so they could be explained to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems:

1. You cannot declare a method within a method. Your `SN` method must be declared outside of the `main` method.
2. The parameter `y` in your `SN` method must have a type. Based on usage, it is probably supposed to be an `int`, so the method signature should look like `SN(int y)`.
3. Despite the method parameter being called `y`, you appear to be using `x` everywhere. You should change `x` to `y` in the `SN` method, since that is the label of the data being passed to the method.
4. As others have pointed out, statements **after** the `return` line are unreachable, and as Matt Coubrough said, your IDE is likely warning you about this. Place it **before** the `return` line.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one problem here is that you have an unreachable statement. Your `System.out.println("THE SUM IS...")` is never reached.

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;

public class natural {

public static int main(String args[]){ 


        int a, s = 0,y; 
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number:");
        int x = in.nextInt();
        public static int SN(y)
        {
            if(x==1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else{
                int N = SN(x-1) + x;
                return N;
}
                System.out.println("THE SUM IS :"+N);
        }

Comment: so what is the solution ???

Comment: Move the println call before the return statement?